# Unable to serialize the session state

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have asp.net web site and trying to change from inproc to sql mode for the session.  I put "serizlizable" attriubte in the user defined classes but I am getting the "Unable to serialize the session state" error page.  It looks like I am referencing another classes in side of the user defined classes that are not marked as "serializable".  I can't mark these classes as "Serializable" since I am only referencing by dll files.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i solve this problem?

By writing other custom classes yourself that you have control over and which you could mark with `Serializable` and storing those custom classes into the session. As far as the mapping between the original classes and those new custom classes is concerned, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could simplify it. That is to say, you cannot store a class into out-of-process session without it being marked as serializable.